# Ordering of three shuffled decks of cards

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

In a card game with a single deck (no jokers), there are $52! = 8.1 * 10^{67}$ ways to order the deck. How many different ways are there for a game played by shuffling three such decks together?

I believe the answer to this question is fairly straightforward. The number of possible orderings would simply be $\frac{156!}{{3!}^{52}}$ if I am not mistaken since we have 3 of each card. Since the value of $52!$ was explicitly mentioned, I am assuming that it should be meaningfully incorporated into this equation somehow but I am not sure how to do it. Thanks and any insights will be well appreciated.

Comment: I think your answer is correct, and your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: You could write your answer as $\dfrac{(3 \times 52)!}{3!^{52}}$ to maximise the number of times $52$ appears but it would not use $52!$ directly

Comment: My guess is that "$52$" is only mentioned that the reader knows how many cards the decks have. Maybe they want to avoid that someone means a skat-deck with only $32$ cards.

Comment: But of course, this number is a multiple of $52!$ ...